# Incomparable hyperdegrees in $\Delta^1_2$, where one of the two is given

Tags: logic, computability

In classical recursion theory, given a set $x 
\le_T 0'$, one can construct a set $y \le_T 0'$ such that $x$ and $y$ are incomparable.

Is the following analogous statement in hyperarithmetical theory true:  given a set (of naturals) $x \in \Delta^1_2$, one can construct a set (of naturals) $y \in \Delta^1_2$ such that $x \not \le_h y$, $y \not \le_h x$?  What if we relax the condition so that we only require $y \not \le_h x$?

Comment: Yes. Such $y$ can be found below $y'$, where $y'$ is the hyperjump of $y$.

Comment: @喻良 Is it possible for you to cite a textbook?

Comment: Technically, you want to assume $x$ is non-hyperarithmetic.

Comment: I don't know any textbook which states the result explicitly. But it is a simple exercise by the Gandy-forcing.